# Outpan API C# POST Request

Tags: api, outpan

What does the Outpan server expect when posting data?
GET was giving me a json info that I was able to convert to an object.

Now when I'm giving information back just like the name:

https://api.outpan.com/v2/products/UPCCode/name?apikey=xxx

it will always not understand my information (error 400). Already tried sending the json back with additional info, "Foodname" and "name = Foodname"

Comment: Any news about this? I have the same issue right now.